# Dataframe to Dictionary including List of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to convert below dataframe to dictionary.
I want to group via column A and take a list of common sequence. for e.g.

**Example 1:**

```
    n1 v1  v2 
2    A  C   3
3    A  D   4
4    A  C   5
5    A  D   6
```

**Expected output:**

```
{'A': [{'C':'3','D':'4'},{'C':'5','D':'6'}]}
```

---

**Example 2:**

```
n1   n2  v1  v2 
s1    A  C   3
s1    A  D   4
s1    A  C   5
s1    A  D   6
s1    B  P   6
s1    B  Q   3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{'s1': {'A': [{'C': 3, 'D': 4}, {'C': 5, 'D': 6}], 'B': {'P': 6, 'Q': 3}}}
```

so basically `C` and `D` are repeating as a sequence,I want to club `C` and `D` in one dictionary and make a list of if it occurs multiple times.

Please note (Currently I am using below code):

```
def recur_dictify(frame):
    if len(frame.columns) == 1:
        if frame.values.size == 1: return frame.values[0][0]
        return frame.values.squeeze()
    grouped = frame.groupby(frame.columns[0])
    d = {k: recur_dictify(g.iloc[:,1:]) for k,g in grouped}
    return d
```

This returns :

```
{s1 : {'A': {'C': array(['3', '5'], dtype=object), 'D': array(['4', '6'], dtype=object),'B':{'E':'5','F':'6'}}
```

Also, there can be another series of `s2` having `E,F,G,E,F,G` repeating and some `X` and `Y` having single values

Comment: does the sequence change or always contain `C` and `D`?

Comment: Hi, please check my updated question, you might get more clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets create a function `dictify` which create a dictionary with top level keys from `name` column and club's the repeating occurrences of values in column `v1` into different sub dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dictify(df):
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    for k, g in df.groupby(['n1', df.groupby(['n1', 'v1']).cumcount()]):
        dct[k[0]].append(dict([*g[['v1', 'v2']].values]))
    return dict(dct)
```

---

```
dictify(df)

{'A': [{'C': 3, 'D': 4}, {'C': 5, 'D': 6}]}
```

#### UPDATE:

In case there can be **variable** number of **primary grouping keys** i.e. `[n1, n2, ...]` we can use a more generic method:

```
def update(dct, keys, val):
    k, *_ = keys
    dct[k] = update(dct.get(k, {}), _, val) if _ \
        else [*np.hstack([dct[k], [val]])] if k in dct else val
    return dct

def dictify(df, keys):
    dct = dict()
    for k, g1 in df.groupby(keys):
        for _, g2 in g1.groupby(g1.groupby('v1').cumcount()):
            update(dct, k, dict([*g2[['v1', 'v2']].values]))

    return dict(dct)
```

---

```
dictify(df, ['n1', 'n2'])

{'s1': {'A': [{'C': 3, 'D': 4}, {'C': 5, 'D': 6}], 'B': {'P': 6, 'Q': 3}}}
```

Comment: Hi, 
thanks.. 
I am posting another related question below please check.. 
occurrence of multiple is not really necessary actually.. want to give a if statement for it.

Comment: Just now, please check

Comment: @PriyalMangla That's a completely different question from the previous one ;)

Comment: Please check my updated question now.. 
basically its dynamic, the ones having updated sequence must be in list and non repeating not in list

Comment: Yes yes I know, actually this was my actual question, couldnt frame it well earlier. 
But thanks a lot, for your answer.. I can use this logic somewhere

Comment: @PriyalMangla Sure will do..Is it ok if the output for lets say the key `B` is `'B': [{'P': 6, 'Q': 3}]` instead of  `'B': {'P': 6, 'Q': 3}`...Because that will make more sense..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221261/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-priyal-mangla).

Comment: I know right, but that's the problem, would want 'B': {'P': 6, 'Q': 3} 
because the final dictionary I am passing to is in zeep python package... 
which expects dictionary of complex type. at some places value type is string and at some places a [ ].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one line statement that solves your problem:

```
def df_to_dict(df):
    return {name: [dict(x.to_dict('split')['data'])
                   for _, x in d.drop('name', 1).groupby(d.index // 2)]
            for name, d in df.groupby('name')}
```

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A'] * 4,
                   'v1': ['C', 'D'] * 2,
                   'v2': [3, 4, 5, 6]})
print(df_to_dict(df))
```

Output:

```
{'A': [{'C': 3, 'D': 4}, {'C': 5, 'D': 6}]}
```

Comment: Thanks :) , I have updated my question, please check?